# IF Statement in batch not working?

Tags: variables, batch-file, if-statement, set, prompt

I'm coding a game in batch right now, and I've not gone very far when I encountered this problem. I'm trying to set a variable for a user answer, then use that answer for an IF statement, but for some reason it always goes to the `:Quit` block. Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
Echo . Are you ready?
Echo Your options are:
call :colorEcho C "================="
Echo.
Echo 1. Yes
Echo 2. No
call :colorEcho C "================="
Echo.
Echo Please enter the number corresponding to your answer.
set /p Answer1 = "Enter your choice: "
if "%Answer1%" == "1" goto Game
if "%Answer1%" == "2" goto Quit

:Quit
Echo You have chosen to quit.
pause
exit

:Game
::Game goes here.
Echo Test
pause

pause
exit

:colorEcho
echo off
<nul set /p ".=%DEL%" > "%~2"
findstr /v /a:%1 /R "^$" "%~2" nul
del "%~2" > nul 2>&1i
```

colorEcho just sets a different color for a string of text.

This is what happens when I run the game:

Option 1 chosen:

[image: Option 1 chosen]

Option 2 chosen:

[image: Option 2 chosen]

Thanks in advance!

Spades

Comment: I suggest taking a look at [choice](http://ss64.com/nt/choice.html), as it's specifically made for these kind of things

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `%Answer1%` is not defined.

```
set /p Answer1 = "Enter your choice: "
```

sets a variable named `%Answer1 %` (note the space!)

Remove the spaces around the `=`.

Comment: Oh my god thank you so much! I should have thought of that before, but it always helps for a fresh set of eyes to look at my code, right? +1 from me!