# drag and drop batch video conversion

Tags: batch-file, video, cmd, ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg to merge videos, I have a bunch *.mp4 and *.m4a with the same name, the manual way to do the conversion is to type the ffmpeg command with the quoted name of the files, I tried to automate and drag and drop both files to merge but I've not being able to pass the file names to variables and then to ffmpeg, I tried this code with quotes, with  `!` instead of `%` but no luck, someone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set "params=!cmdcmdline!"
set "params=!params:~0,-1!"
set "params=!params:*" =!"
set count=0
for %%G IN (!params!) do (
  if %%~xG==.m4a (
        set myaudio=%%~G)
  if %%~xG==.mp4 (
        set myvideo=%%~G )
)
  C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -y -i "%myaudio%" -i "%myvideo%" -c copy "%myvideo%_new.mp4"
pause
exit
```

edit: I had wrong syntaxis, as stated on the comments, removing the extra spaces solved the problem

Comment: To **use** delayed expansion you need to change the percent sign inside the (code block) to an exclamation mark. Also there are some closing parenthesis missing.

Comment: I do tried with exclamation marks but it doesn't work, I tried something like this
`@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set "params=!cmdcmdline!"
set "params=!params:~0,-1!"
set "params=!params:*" =!"
set count=0
for %%G IN (!params!) do (
  if %%~xG == .m4a (
        set myaudio = %%~G)
  if %%~xG == .mp4 (
        set myvideo = %%~G )
echo a = !myaudio!
echo v = !myvideo!
)
  C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -y -i "%myaudio%" -i "%myvideo%" -c copy "%myvideo%_new.mp4"
pause
exit`

Comment: Sorry, but I do ignore code in comments as the line breaks are missing, please edit your question to include additional/changed code.

Comment: you've got an [syntax problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36252350/2152082)

Comment: hold on, it worked :)