# Using variables to specify a part of a file name in CMD

Tags: variables, cmd, xcopy

I'm trying to move files from one portion a system to another using an inputted variable but for some reason xcopy won't use wildcards or variables.

```
set /p EIID = "Enter Aircraft EI_ID:"

xcopy C:\ULLSA\Data\ARCHIVE\IN\"%EIID%.LogbookData.qep" E:\ULLS_MEDIA\Data\3rdParty\ARCHIVE 

xcopy C:\ULLSA\Data\ARCHIVE\IN\"%EIID%.LogbookData.qep" "E:\ULLS_MEDIA\Data\MigOut\%EIID%"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copying Files with Wildcards in the Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609028/copying-files-with-wildcards-in-the-path)

Comment: you've got a [syntax problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36252350/2152082)

Answer (score 0):

Have a go at this one mate. No need to quotations unless you believe there will be spaces in the file path. Also close your file path otherwise it wont work bud.

```
set /p EIID=Enter Aircraft EI_ID: 

xcopy C:\ULLSA\Data\ARCHIVE\IN\%EIID%.LogbookData.qep E:\ULLS_MEDIA\Data\3rdParty\ARCHIVE\

xcopy C:\ULLSA\Data\ARCHIVE\IN\%EIID%.LogbookData.qep E:\ULLS_MEDIA\Data\MigOut\%EIID%\
```